# Kendo ui in angular js directive transclusion

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-directive

Currently I'm testing kendo ui controls with angular js. I',m trying to create my own directive which is using kendo auto complete control. It looks like this:

```
app.directive('testCompile', [ '$log','$compile', function ($log, $compile) {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        controller: function () {

        },
        controllerAs: 'testctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        compile: function compile(tElement:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, tAttrs: ng.IAttributes,tTransclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, iAttrs:ng.IAttributes, controller, iTransclude) {
                    iTransclude(function (clone) {
                        var html = '<input id="test-id" test-compile"test" type="text" kendo-auto-complete class="k-input" k-data-source=""/>';
                        var compiled = $compile(html)(scope);
                        iElement.replaceWith(compiled);

                    });


                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, iAttrs:ng.IAttributes, controller, iTransclude) {

                }
            }
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
}]);
```

It should generate part of html like this:

```
<span tabindex="-1" role="presentation" class="k-widget k-autocomplete k-header k-input form-control k-state-default">
    <input id="test-id" type="text" kendo-auto-complete="" class="k-input form-control" k-data-source="" data-role="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="city2_listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="k-icon k-loading" style="display:none">
    </span>
</span>
```

But unfortunately it generates only this:

```
<input id="test-id" type="text" kendo-auto-complete="" class="k-input form-control" k-data-source="" data-role="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="city2_listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" style="width: 100%;">
```

Spans are not generated.

What am I doing wrong?